# Как напечатать объекты типов str и int в одной строчке, и почему str превращается в NoneType (Python 3)

Tags: python, print, типы

Добрый день, коллеги. Необходимо напечатать в одной строчке обычные слова в кавычках (простите за отсутствие терминологии) и переменную, имеющую числовое значение.

Вот первый вариант кода:

```
score = 1

def gameover(score):
    print ("Игра пройдена на ") + (score)

gameover(score)
```

Он выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Попробовал убрать плюсик, ошибка стала

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Попробовал изменить центральную часть кода на это:

```
def gameover(score):
    print ("Игра пройдена на %s процетнов") % (score)
```

Ошибка, как и в первом примере:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Как это понимать, и что с этим делать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все параметры одной функции `print` должны быть заключены в общие скобки (это верно не только для функции `print`, но и для любой другой функции). Если параметров несколько, то они должны быть разделены запятой.

В первом варианте правильно будет так:

```
print("Игра пройдена на", score)  # запятая сама добавляет пробел, поэтому пробел в конце строки не нужен
```

Или так:

```
print("Игра пройдена на " + str(score))
```

Обратите внимание, что тут нужно явное преобразование числа к строке через `str()` (нельзя просто взять и "сложить" строку с числом).

Для второго варианта правильно вот так:

```
print("Игра пройдена на %s процентов" % score)
```

Оператор `%` действует между строкой и подставляемыми значениями, и результат операции опять же должен находиться внутри скобок, "принадлежащих" функции `print`. В принципе, можно было бы просто добавить еще одни общие скобки, но тогда скобки вокруг строки и `score` будут излишними:

```
print(("Игра пройдена на %s процентов") % (score))  # Не делайте так!
```

## По поводу ошибок:

Функция `print()` возвращает None. Получается, что когда вы делаете

```
print ("Игра пройдена на ") + (score)
```

то после вызова `print` это выражение превращается в

```
None + score
```

Отсюда ошибка, что `None` и `int` нельзя складывать.

Если плюс убрать, то получится

```
None(score)
```

т.е. попытка вызова `None` как функции с параметром `score`.

Во втором варианте после вызова `print` получается вот это:

```
None % score
```

Опять же, ошибка как раз и говорит о том, что оператор `%` не поддерживает аргументы типов `NoneType` и `int`.

Comment: Не совсем понимал принципы этих скобочек, потому что переходил с Python 2. Огромное вам спасибо!